# How to display french accent in a beamer table?

Tags: tables, beamer

I have a table in french, it is correctly displayed with latex, but when I put it in beamer it does not display the accent, for example république in the first line

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\frametitle{Extraction de CF bilingues}
\begin{itemize}
\begin{table}
\caption{Exemple de CF en Italien et en Français}
\centering
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline

CF_{it}  &CF_{fr} \\
\hline

 \left\{repubblica\right\}, \left\{7, 22,..., 48972\right\}&  \left\{ r\'{e} publique\right\}, \left\{6 98,..., 42558\right\}\\ 
  \left\{regina, londra\right\}, \left\{36, 180,..., 48762\right\}&  \left\{reine, londres\right\}, \left\{785, 1368,..., 42572\right\}\\ 
\left\{dibattito\_politico\right\}, \left\{554, 1299,..., 48764\right\}&  \left\{débat\_politique\right\}, \left\{222, 995,..., 37942\right\}\\ 

\hline

\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab\string:CC}
\end{table}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

How can I show the accentuated character, the problem is caused by the { character

Comment: Why do you load both `babel` and `polyglossia`?

Comment: There is more than one "French accent" or, more precisely, more than one accented character that can occur with some non-negligible frequency in a French-language document. E.g., there's `é`, `è`, `ê`, `à`, `ç` -- and a few more. Which one(s) do you have in mind?

Comment: @Mico in my case 'é'

Comment: @Bernad I add it now because the accents was not detected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

- Don't load both `babel` and `polyglossia`. Load one or the other package, *but not both*.
- There's a stray `\begin{itemize}` statement: delete it.
- The 12 `\left` and `\right` sizing directives do absolutely nothing except create havoc. Get rid of them.
- Assuming `CF_{it}` and `CF_{fr}` should employ subscript mode, you should write them as `CF$_{\mathsf{it}}$` and `CF$_{\mathsf{fr}}$.
- Last but not least, do load the `inputenc` and `fontenc` packages, with options `[utf8]` and `[T1]`, respectively, and do use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline`.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Extraction de CF bilingues}
\begin{table}
\caption{Exemple de CF en Italien et en Français} \label{tab\string:CC}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\centering
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\toprule
CF$_{\mathsf{it}}$  & CF$_{\mathsf{fr}}$ \\
\midrule
    \{repubblica\}, \{7, 22,..., 48972\}
 &  \{r\'{e}publique\}, \{6 98,..., 42558\}  \\
    \{regina, londra\}, \{36, 180,..., 48762\}
 &  \{reine, londres\}, \{785, 1368,..., 42572\}  \\
    \{dibattito\_politico\}, \{554, 1299,..., 48764\}
 &  \{débat\_politique\}, \{222, 995,..., 37942\}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice answer. I upvote +1.

Comment: @Mico CF$_{\mathsf{it}}$, i think CF$_{it}$  is suffisant, what is the utility of \toprule instead of \hline?

Comment: @Che - `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` produce well-spaced lines; `\hline` does not. If you prefer a cramped “look”, by all means stick with `\hline`.

Comment: @Che - About your "i think `CF$_{it}$` is suffisant" (as opposed to `CF$_{\mathsf{it}}$` in my code): it really depends on the "look" you wish to achieve. Your solution will typeset the "it" in slanted mode, whereas mine typesets the subscript in "upright", i.e., non-slanted mode. Given that you don't employ slanted characters anywhere else in the table, I thought it's more appropriate to avoid the slanted look in the two subscripts. For sure, though, reasonable people can disagree as to what the appropriate "look" should be.